# <--- Last few GCs ---> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, deployment, node-modules

I  have been receiving this error when I try to run my react program in VS code. I have tried every single method to resolve my issue but not working at all. i try to increase memory but somehow its not been increasing when I see its been updated or not.
The command i use to increase the memory is

```
 set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=5120"
```

I have tried until 16384 as well multiple of 1024. When I try to check the memory it shows about 8192 on windows shell and 2048 on VS code terminal and when try to update on both by above command its not making any difference. The command i use to check memory is below

```
  node -e 'console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))'
```

Please you got any idea to resolve this issue please do let me know.. Thanks

Comment: So, did you expect your program to use up that much memory, or do you have a memory leak?

Comment: i don't think there is any memory leakage i just need more memory because it was running nothing changed a bit and it started to give that problem, but somehow memory allocation not being updated